# SQL Server compare Smalldatetime with date time string

Tags: sql-server, date

I cant seem to find any examples where people are using the smalldatetime type to query with anything other than the date. I can get queries to work with the date, but it ignores the time. I have a row in the table with a date of "`24/06/2016 12:10:00`". I want to query this table to pull all rows where date AND time are less than the current time. The issue is that it completely ignores the time and only matches with the date. Using the following where clause i wouldnt expect any results as the row in the table is 12:10.

```
WHERE startdate < '2016-06-24 12:00:00'
```

How do i format the query so that the server will take the time into affect when returning the results.

Comment: How is your database collation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue must be something else, as my where clauses using smalldatetime do indeed take the time component into account...

```
WITH TestData as (
SELECT
    cast('2016-24-06 11:50:00' as smalldatetime) as TheDate
UNION ALL
SELECT
    cast('2016-24-06 12:10:00' as smalldatetime) as TheDate
)
select * from TestData
WHERE TheDate < cast('2016-24-06 12:00:00' as smalldatetime)
```

Perhaps explicitly cast the date in the Where clause to also be a smalldatetime?